# Automating SAS to calculate dates in various formats and store in macro variables

Tags: sas, sql

The background is I need to pull data from several sources and put it together, using SQL in SAS.  And, I want to automate it as much as possible.  So, for one, I want to have a small number of inputs (into macro variables) where several other values (I would think also macro variables) are calculated based on the inputs, so that I can use these various values in the queries.  One thing that makes things a bit harder is, since these are used in SQL WHERE statements, some need to be inside single quotes, which is more difficult with SAS macros.  In fact, I think the single quotes is my main issue and I think I have been able to get the rest.

Okay, so here are the inputs.

```
%LET Report_Year = 2015; 
%LET Report_Month = 08;
```

Now, from that, I want to be able to store the value

```
'201508'
```

in a macro variable.  I googled around and found something like the following, but it doesn't appear to actually work.

```
%LET Format1 = %unquote(%str(%'&Report_Year&Report_Month%'));
```

I also need to get other "dates" in this same format, such as the month 3 months earlier.  But, if I can get the first, I think I can handle the 3 months earlier part with something like the following:

```
%LET BEG_DT = %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(inputn(&Report_Year&Report_Month, yymmn6.)), -2, S), yymmn6.);
```

There are other formats I need, such as the following format:

```
'2015-08-31'
```

Again, it's not just this date, but also 3 months before or 12 months before, etc, but again I think I can handle that part.  If I get help with the first format, I'm pretty sure I can figure out this one simply by using the same code and changing the date format (and using "E" as the last input in the intnx function for end of the month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out now.  The %unquote was the problem.  I needed to remove it.

For example,

```
%LET Format1 = %str(%'&Report_Year&Report_Month%');
```